# как сделать вывод символов в ряд?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
h = int(input('введите число символов | '))

for i in range(h):
    liters = ['安', '吧', '八', '爸', '百', '北', '不', '大', '岛', '的', '弟', '地', '东', '都', '对', '多',
              '儿', '二', '港', '哥', '个', '关', '贵', '国', '过', '海', '好', '很', '会', '家', '见', '叫',
              '姐', '京', '九', '可', '老', '李', '零', '六', '吗', '妈', '么', '没', '美', '妹', '们', '名',
              '明', '哪', '那', '南', '你', '您', '朋', '七', '起', '千', '去', '人', '认', '日', '三', '上', '谁',
              '什', '生', '师', '十', '识', '是', '四', '他', '她', '台', '天', '湾', '万', '王', '我', '五', '西', '息', '系',
              '先', '香', '想', '小', '谢', '姓', '休', '学', '也', '一', '亿', '英', '友', '月', '再', '张', '这', '中',
              '字', ]

    print(random.choice(liters))
```

вывод получается:

```
1
1
1
1
```

а надо:

```
1111
```

Comment: печатайте так `print(random.choice(liters), end=" ")`, по-умолчанию `end` равен переводу строки

Comment: спасибо, работает